# How to save ToolBar Layout?

Tags: c#, wpf

Yes I have googled the crap ola out of this.. I can't seem to find where anyone is trying to save the user edits (as in the re positioning of the toolbars inside the toolbartray) for the layout of their toolbar.. This is either so simple I am an idiot, or hard.. I can't even seem to find a starting point, like what are the properties I would want to save out and load? Surely not x,y,width and height? Is this just something I should consider getting a 3rd party tool for?

Basically what I want to do is save the position of the toolbars that are on the tool bar after the user moves them around in the toolbar tray.

My Xaml Looks something like this:

```
<src:BaseWindow x:Class="RPDM.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:c1="http://schemas.componentone.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:RPDM"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800" Loaded="OnLoaded">
<src:BaseWindow.Resources>

<DockPanel x:Name="dockMain">

    <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="tbMain">
        <ToolBar  Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowToolBarFile, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <Button Click="mnuFileNewProject_Click" ToolTip="New Dataflow Project">
                <Image Source="{StaticResource imgNewDataFlow_24}" Width="24" Height="24"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="mnuFileNewAutomation_Click" ToolTip="New Automation Project">
                <Image Source="{StaticResource imgNewAutomation_24}" Width="24" Height="24"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="mnuFileOpen_Click" ToolTip="Open">
                <Image Source="{StaticResource imgOpen_24}" Width="24" Height="24"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="mnuFileSave_Click" ToolTip="Save">
                <Image Source="{StaticResource imgSave_24}" Width="24" Height="24"/>
            </Button>
        </ToolBar>
        <ToolBar  Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowToolBarLayout, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <Button Click="mnuLayoutZoomIn_Click" ToolTip="Zoom In">
                <Image Source="{StaticResource imgZoomIn_24}" Width="24" Height="24"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="mnuLayoutZoomOut_Click" ToolTip="Zoom Out">
                <Image Source="{StaticResource imgZoomOut_24}" Width="24" Height="24"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="mnuLayoutZoomToFit_Click" ToolTip="Zoom to Fit">
                <Image Source="{StaticResource imgFitToView_24}" Width="24" Height="24"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Click="btnToggleOrientation_Click" ToolTip="Toggle Orientation">
                <Image Source="{StaticResource imgOrientation_24}" Width="24" Height="24"/>
            </Button>
        </ToolBar>
 </ToolBarTray>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: OK Sorry I will edit with more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialize the root element of the logical tree by using [XamlWriter.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter.save(v=vs.110).aspx) method and then reload it by the help of [XamlReader.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.load(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

I think this will work for you. For more reference go to this msdn thread :

[Trying to programmatically save and restore control layouts](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/79ac3c2b-ea03-42e0-99d3-9d2b96b25971/trying-to-programmatically-save-and-restore-control-layouts?forum=wpf)